# Update mysql table only if all entries of another table match a certain condition

Tags: mysql, sql-update, exists, correlated-subquery

is it possible in MySQL to update a certain table only if all of the rows of another table match a certain condition? Let me give you an example with a database having two tables:

TableA: id INT, completed BOOLEAN

TableB: total INT, progress INT, tableA_id INT

Can I update TableA setting 'completed=1' if all of the entries of TableB have total==progress?
I was thinking about using CASE:

```
UPDATE TableA SET completed = CASE WHEN (SELECT..) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END WHERE id = x
```

Of course I don't know how to proceed... Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Does TableA contain only 1 row or do you want all the rows to be updated?

Comment: Well, it contains several rows with an id which is the foreign key of the TableB entries. I'll update the post to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause of the `UPDATE` statement which checks the min value of the boolean expression `total = progress`.
If it is `1` which means `true`, then there is no row in `TableB` where `total <> progress`:

```
UPDATE TableA a 
SET a.completed = 1
WHERE (SELECT MIN(b.total = b.progress) FROM TableB b WHERE b.tableA_id = a.id) = 1; -- For MySql you may even omit =1
```

If there is always at least 1 row in `TableB` for each `TableA.id` you could also use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE TableA a 
SET a.completed = 1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM TableB b
  WHERE b.tableA_id = a.id AND b.total <> b.progress
);
```